# C# Serialize JSON to simple Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have following json:

```
{
    "Name" : "Value1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "UserName": "test",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "UserInformation": {
                "City": "city",
                "country:": "country"
            }
        },        
        {
            "UserName": "test1",
            "email": "test1@test.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want get next dictionary:

```
{
    "Name" : "Value1",
    "Data[0].UserName": "test",
    "Data[0].email": "test@test.com",
    "Data[0].UserInformation.City": "city",
    "Data[0].UserInformation.country": "country",
    "Data[1].UserName": "test1",
    "Data[1].email": "test1@test.com"
}
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json don't help resolving my problem. Please, can you help me?

Comment: That's some odd requirement. Have you seen [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/)? This site can convert your JSON to C# classes which you can use to deserialize your JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like this (using Newtonsoft.Json):

```
var dictionary = JObject.Parse(json)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JValue>()
    .ToDictionary(jv => jv.Path, jv => jv.ToString());
```